# SQL Server OVER() clause not behaving as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I'm using the `OVER()` clause to get the running total of payments based on account number and the date the payment was made. I'm then subtracting that running total from the current balance to determine the balance after each transaction was made

```
SELECT
    no_,
    amount,
    SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY no_ ORDER BY effectiveDate DESC) AS RunningTotal,
    balance - (SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY no_ ORDER BY effectiveDate DESC)) + amount AS CalculatedBalance,
    balance
FROM 
    c
WHERE 
    status != 'closed'
ORDER BY 
    no_
```

It works fine for positive numbers, but when the amount field is a negative number, I get weird outputs like below:

[image]

This happens for all negative numbers, I've checked all my positive numbers and they are correct. I looked online and I can't find a reason for OVER() not accepting negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing the calculation in reverse?  I would expect logic more like this:

```
SELECT no_, amount,
       SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY no_ ORDER BY effectiveDate ASC) AS RunningTotal,
       (balance + amount +
        SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY no_ ORDER BY effectiveDate ASC)
       ) AS CalculatedBalance,
       balance
FROM c
WHERE status <> 'closed'
ORDER BY no_;
```

In addition, because `balance` is negative, you want to *add* the amounts rather than subtract them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be made aware of the **`ROWS BETWEEN PRECEDING`** clause.

> In the window frame clause, you indicate the window frame units (ROWS
>   or RANGE) and the window frame extent (the delimiters). With the ROWS
>   window frame unit, you can indicate the delimiters as one of three
>   options:
>
> ■■ UNBOUNDED PRECEDING or FOLLOWING, meaning the beginning or end of
>   the partition, respectively
>
> ■■ CURRENT ROW, obviously representing the current row
>
> ■■  ROWS PRECEDING or FOLLOWING, meaning n rows before or after the
>   current, respectively

Example with syntax:

TEMP QUERY TO GROUP THE DAYS FOUND IN THE DATASET (1..7..infinity)

```
, DENSE_RANK() 
    OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.Account ORDER BY tbl.Date DESC)
    AS [calcDayRankdenseGroup]
```

FINAL RESULTS:

```
select 
    cte.* 
    , SUM(cte.Amount) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY cte.Account ORDER BY cte.calcDayRankdenseGroup ASC
            ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW)
        AS [Amount_RunningTotalDaysLast7]
from cteDateRankAdded cte
order by Account, DATE DESC
```

Data returned from my testing data (seen below):

```
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| Account | Amount | DATE       | calcDayRankGroup_DoNotUse | calcDayRankdenseGroup | calcDayCountInGroup | Amount_RunningTotalDaysLast7 |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 30.00  | 2018-09-16 | 1                         | 1                     | 1                   | 30.00                        |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 69.00  | 2018-09-16 | 1                         | 1                     | 2                   | 99.00                        |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 6.00   | 2018-09-13 | 3                         | 2                     | 1                   | 105.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 57.00  | 2018-09-12 | 4                         | 3                     | 1                   | 162.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 13.00  | 2018-09-12 | 4                         | 3                     | 2                   | 175.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 98.00  | 2018-09-12 | 4                         | 3                     | 3                   | 273.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 47.00  | 2018-09-03 | 7                         | 4                     | 1                   | 320.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 90.00  | 2018-09-02 | 8                         | 5                     | 1                   | 410.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 90.00  | 2018-09-02 | 8                         | 5                     | 2                   | 470.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 32.00  | 2018-08-29 | 10                        | 6                     | 1                   | 433.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 50.00  | 2018-08-24 | 11                        | 7                     | 1                   | 477.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 48.00  | 2018-08-24 | 11                        | 7                     | 2                   | 468.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 100.00 | 2018-08-23 | 13                        | 8                     | 1                   | 555.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 63.00  | 2018-08-20 | 14                        | 9                     | 1                   | 520.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 1       | 49.00  | 2018-08-19 | 15                        | 10                    | 1                   | 522.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 38.00  | 2018-09-16 | 1                         | 1                     | 1                   | 38.00                        |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 3.00   | 2018-09-16 | 1                         | 1                     | 2                   | 41.00                        |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 83.00  | 2018-09-13 | 3                         | 2                     | 1                   | 124.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 28.00  | 2018-09-12 | 4                         | 3                     | 1                   | 152.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 78.00  | 2018-09-12 | 4                         | 3                     | 2                   | 230.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 32.00  | 2018-09-12 | 4                         | 3                     | 3                   | 262.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 29.00  | 2018-09-03 | 7                         | 4                     | 1                   | 291.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 64.00  | 2018-09-02 | 8                         | 5                     | 1                   | 355.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 81.00  | 2018-09-02 | 8                         | 5                     | 2                   | 398.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 60.00  | 2018-08-29 | 10                        | 6                     | 1                   | 455.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 82.00  | 2018-08-24 | 11                        | 7                     | 1                   | 454.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 66.00  | 2018-08-24 | 11                        | 7                     | 2                   | 492.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 9.00   | 2018-08-23 | 13                        | 8                     | 1                   | 423.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 45.00  | 2018-08-20 | 14                        | 9                     | 1                   | 436.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2       | 43.00  | 2018-08-19 | 15                        | 10                    | 1                   | 450.00                       |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+
```

---

Here is the sample data I created to represent your scenario, with today being 9/18/2018.

```
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| Seq | Account | DATE       | Amount | dataDaysAgoDelta | dataDaysAgoGroup |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 1   | 1       | 2018-08-19 | 49.00  | 30               | 10               |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 2   | 1       | 2018-08-20 | 63.00  | 29               | 9                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 3   | 1       | 2018-08-23 | 100.00 | 26               | 8                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 4   | 1       | 2018-08-24 | 50.00  | 25               | 7                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 5   | 1       | 2018-08-24 | 48.00  | 25               | 7                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 6   | 1       | 2018-08-29 | 32.00  | 20               | 6                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 7   | 1       | 2018-09-02 | 90.00  | 16               | 5                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 8   | 1       | 2018-09-02 | 90.00  | 16               | 5                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 9   | 1       | 2018-09-03 | 47.00  | 15               | 4                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 10  | 1       | 2018-09-12 | 57.00  | 6                | 3                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 11  | 1       | 2018-09-12 | 13.00  | 6                | 3                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 12  | 1       | 2018-09-12 | 98.00  | 6                | 3                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 13  | 1       | 2018-09-13 | 6.00   | 5                | 2                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 14  | 1       | 2018-09-16 | 30.00  | 2                | 1                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 15  | 1       | 2018-09-16 | 69.00  | 2                | 1                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 16  | 2       | 2018-08-19 | 43.00  | 30               | 10               |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 17  | 2       | 2018-08-20 | 45.00  | 29               | 9                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 18  | 2       | 2018-08-23 | 9.00   | 26               | 8                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 19  | 2       | 2018-08-24 | 82.00  | 25               | 7                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 20  | 2       | 2018-08-24 | 66.00  | 25               | 7                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 21  | 2       | 2018-08-29 | 60.00  | 20               | 6                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 22  | 2       | 2018-09-02 | 64.00  | 16               | 5                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 23  | 2       | 2018-09-02 | 81.00  | 16               | 5                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 24  | 2       | 2018-09-03 | 29.00  | 15               | 4                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 25  | 2       | 2018-09-12 | 28.00  | 6                | 3                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 26  | 2       | 2018-09-12 | 78.00  | 6                | 3                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 27  | 2       | 2018-09-12 | 32.00  | 6                | 3                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 28  | 2       | 2018-09-13 | 83.00  | 5                | 2                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 29  | 2       | 2018-09-16 | 38.00  | 2                | 1                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
| 30  | 2       | 2018-09-16 | 3.00   | 2                | 1                |
+-----+---------+------------+--------+------------------+------------------+
```

COMPLETE QUERY:

```
DECLARE @tblDaysLast7Found as table
    (Seq int, Account int, DATE date, Amount numeric(10,2), dataDaysAgoDelta int, dataDaysAgoGroup int)

INSERT INTO @tblDaysLast7Found 
    (Seq, Account, DATE, Amount, dataDaysAgoDelta, dataDaysAgoGroup)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '8/19/2018', 49, 30, 10)
    ,(2, 1,  '8/20/2018', 63, 29, 9)
    ,(3, 1,  '8/23/2018', 100, 26, 8)
    ,(4, 1,  '8/24/2018', 50, 25, 7)
    ,(5, 1,  '8/24/2018', 48, 25, 7)
    ,(6, 1,  '8/29/2018', 32, 20, 6)
    ,(7, 1,  '9/2/2018', 90, 16, 5)
    ,(8, 1,  '9/2/2018', 90, 16, 5)
    ,(9, 1,  '9/3/2018', 47, 15, 4)
    ,(10, 1, '9/12/2018', 57, 6, 3)
    ,(11, 1, '9/12/2018', 13, 6, 3)
    ,(12, 1, '9/12/2018', 98, 6, 3)
    ,(13, 1, '9/13/2018', 6, 5, 2)
    ,(14, 1, '9/16/2018', 30, 2, 1)
    ,(15, 1, '9/16/2018', 69, 2, 1)
    ,(16, 2, '8/19/2018', 43, 30, 10)
    ,(17, 2, '8/20/2018', 45, 29, 9)
    ,(18, 2, '8/23/2018', 9, 26, 8)
    ,(19, 2, '8/24/2018', 82, 25, 7)
    ,(20, 2, '8/24/2018', 66, 25, 7)
    ,(21, 2, '8/29/2018', 60, 20, 6)
    ,(22, 2, '9/2/2018', 64, 16, 5)
    ,(23, 2, '9/2/2018', 81, 16, 5)
    ,(24, 2, '9/3/2018', 29, 15, 4)
    ,(25, 2, '9/12/2018', 28, 6, 3)
    ,(26, 2, '9/12/2018', 78, 6, 3)
    ,(27, 2, '9/12/2018', 32, 6, 3)
    ,(28, 2, '9/13/2018', 83, 5, 2)
    ,(29, 2, '9/16/2018', 38, 2, 1)
    ,(30, 2, '9/16/2018', 3, 2, 1)

--select * from @tblDaysLast7Found

;WITH cteDateRankAdded AS
(
select -- * 
    tbl.Account
    , tbl.Amount
    , tbl.DATE
    , RANK() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.Account ORDER BY tbl.Date DESC)
        AS [calcDayRankGroup_DoNotUse]
    , DENSE_RANK() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.Account ORDER BY tbl.Date DESC)
        AS [calcDayRankdenseGroup]
    , ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.Account, tbl.Date ORDER BY tbl.Date DESC)
        AS [calcDayCountInGroup]
from 
    @tblDaysLast7Found tbl
)

select 
    cte.* 
    , SUM(cte.Amount) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY cte.Account ORDER BY cte.calcDayRankdenseGroup ASC
            ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW)
        AS [Amount_RunningTotalDaysLast7]
from cteDateRankAdded cte
order by Account, DATE DESC
```